# SQL/ Bigquery rank or row_number that resets when column changes value

Tags: sql, row, rank, gaps-and-islands

I have a sql (bigquery) table like below.

```
| Name  | DaysToGo |Task    |ID  |
|:-----:|:--------:|:------:|:--:|
| Joe   | 50       | A      | 1  |
| Joe   | 49       | A      | 2  |
| Joe   | 48       | B      | 1  |
| Joe   | 47       | B      | 2  |
| Joe   | 46       | B      | 3  |
| Joe   | 45       | A      | 1  |
| Joe   | 47       | A      | 2  |
| Joe   | 46       | A      | 3  |
| Tim   | 50       | B      | 1  |
| Tim   | 49       | B      | 2  |
| Tim   | 48       | B      | 3  |
| Tim   | 47       | C      | 1  |
| Tim   | 46       | B      | 1  |
| Tim   | 45       | B      | 2  |
| Tim   | 47       | C      | 1  |
| Tim   | 46       | C      | 2  |
```

I am looking to create the "ID" column based on changes in the "Task" column, partitioning by name. Essentially, "ID" should reset to 1 every time the "Task" changes and restart the ID counter from 1.

I tried Rank, row number and even lag functions but don't seem to be able to get to a proper solution. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  In this case, I would recommend the difference of row numbers:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by name, task, seqnum - seqnum_t
                          order by daystogo desc
                         ) as id
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by daystogo) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by name, task order by daystogo) as seqnum_t
      from t
     ) t;
```

Why this works is a little difficult to explain.  If you stare at the results of the subquery, you will see how the difference between the two `row_number()` values identifies the adjacent tasks for each person.  The outer query uses this difference to assign a new `row_number()` for the final result.

Comment: Thank you @Gordon.